# Counting unbalanced brackets in Python. How could I improve my code?

Tags: python

I've heard that counting unbalanced brackets program is a good knowledge-verification task for a begginer. So i wrote one. It does the job but it could do better imo. Could someone give me any hints(NOT straight answers) what could I improve? Is there a way of setting one universal regular expression instead of 4 like i did?

```
import re
lstCH = ['<','>','(',')','[',']','{','}']   # List of allowed characters

def isbr(string):                           #To make sure that string consists only of characters in lstCH
    for x in range(len(string)):
        if string[x] in lstCH:
            continue
        else:
            return False
    return True

def eliminate(string, Search_Method):       #function that 'strips' line(string) out of characters that match regular expression(Search_Method)
    tab = list(string)
    while 1:
        ko = Search_Method.search(string)
        if ko != None:
            del tab[ko.end()-1]
            del tab[ko.start()]
            string = ''.join(str(x)for x in tab)
        else:
            break
    return string

RegEx1 = re.compile(r'''#Regular expressions that match closed pairs of brackets with whatever inside
(
\<
(.*)*
\>
)
''',re.VERBOSE)
RegEx2 = re.compile(r'''
(
\(
(.*)*
\)
)
''',re.VERBOSE)
RegEx3 = re.compile(r'''
(
\[
(.*)*
\]
)
''',re.VERBOSE)
RegEx4 = re.compile(r'''
(
\{
(.*)*
\}
)
''',re.VERBOSE)
while 1:             #main loop
    print("Enter a line(or press Ctrl+C to exit): ", end='')
    try:
        string = input()
        if isbr(string)==False:
            print('You have entered characters other than brackets.')
            continue
        result = eliminate(eliminate(eliminate(eliminate(string,RegEx1),RegEx2),RegEx3),RegEx4) ##Nesting eliminate function inside itself with different 2nd parameter at each level. One type of brackets at a time :/
        if len(result)==1:                      #result is a string that consists of brackets with no pair. Lenght of that string is my solution
            print("There is 1 missing bracket")
        else:
            print("There are %d missing brackets"%len(result))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Bye!")
        break
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](//codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Comment: Consider using a stack....

Comment: If your code is working, then it belongs on [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Also, you might as well write the regexes on a single line.